# How to convert long number string value to numeric value using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

User is allowed to insert up to 25 value in `textbox`.

```
i.e. 1234567890123456789012345
```

On change event of textbox I need to convert that same into numeric value to perform numeric operations and then after need to display same entered value with thousand separator along with 2 decimal places.

I tried the following code:

1. `Number($('#textbox1').val()).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`
2. `parseInt($('#textbox1').val(), 10).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`

Both gives me following output

```
1.2,345,679,801,234,568e+21
```

expected output:-

```
1,234,567,890,123,456,789,012,345.00
```

Comment: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is the largest precise integer value available and your value is larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using autoNumeric js. Find it [here](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 0):

something like this work for you? I found it on the internet...

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2 + '.00';
}
```

Comment: not sure about the numeric part, but this will get you commas. code from: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 0):

for the numeric point of view, still i could not get any solution at JavaScript, so I have posted the value to server side and get JSon result.

But for the display purpose I have did finally :

```
function ChangeAmountFormat(target) {
var $this = $(target);
var num = $this.val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/(\s)/g, '');
var decimalPointDeleted = '';

if (lastValue.length > 0 && lastValue.indexOf('.') > 0 && num.indexOf('.') < 0) {
    decimalPointDeleted = 'y';
}

if (num.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
    var numSplitValues = num.split('.');
    num = numSplitValues[0].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    num += (num.length > 0 ? ('.' + numSplitValues[1]) : '');
}
else {
    if (decimalPointDeleted == 'y' && num.toString().substring((num.length - 2), num.length) == '00') {
        var tempNum = num.toString().substring(0, (num.length - 2));
        num = tempNum + '.' + num.toString().substring((num.length - 2), num.length);
    }
    else {
        num = num + (num.length > 0 ? '.00' : '');
    }

    num = num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

$this.val(num);
}
```

here, some more things also handles. Kindly ignore.